# return the difference between maximum and minimum value of float items in a list

Tags: python, data-analysis

I am trying to return the difference of max and min of float items in the sequence. The output shall be an int, but the algorithm given below returns a list instead. Could someone let me know what I am missing?

```
def flatten(*args):
    res = []
    for el in args:
        if isinstance(el,(tuple)):
            if el != ():
                res.extend(flatten(*el))
                continue
            else:
                return "Empty"
        res.append(el)
    diff = [max(res)-min(res)]
    return diff
>>> a
(1, 2)
>>> b
(1, (7, 8))
>>> flatten(a,b)
[1]
```

Answer (score 0):

The following `flatten(*args)` function returns the difference between the highest number parameter value given and the lowest number parameter value given:

```
def flatten(*args):
  return max(args) - min(args)
```

example calls to `flatten(*args)`:

```
>>> flatten(1,2)
1
>>> flatten(10,2)
8
>>> flatten(10,2,20)
18
```

Answer (score 0):

When you assign diff, you have max(res) - min(res) inside square brackets, which is used only when you have elements in a list.

Instead, do the following:

diff = max(res) - min(res)